# Que ocurre realmente cuando uso los siguientes comandos en PSQL

Tags: postgresql, terminal

Soy nuevo en todo el tema de las bases de datos y desde hace muy poco estoy usando `Postgres`. Vi en algun foro que para "arrancar" postgres debias usar los siguientes comandos ...

`~ sudo su - postgres`

`~ psql`

Sin embargo, tengo entendido que, para realizar una conexion con una base de datos, es necesario un cliente y un servidor, en este caso, mi PC hace ambas labores, pero mi pregunta es: cual de los dos comandos "arranca" el servidor y cual "arranca" el cliente?

Comment: El primero es el arranque del servidor, es el único comando que necesitas para arrancar el servicio o motor de BD, el segundo es el cliente de consulta.

Comment: Gracias Maestro!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

el comando sudo se utiliza en sistemas operativos basados en Unix, como Linux, para conceder temporalmente permisos de superusuario (root) a un usuario o programa que los necesite para realizar una tarea determinada.

La sintaxis básica del comando "sudo" es la siguiente:

```
sudo [comando o programa]
```

El comando "su" (switch user) se utiliza en sistemas operativos basados en Unix, como Linux, para cambiar el usuario actual a otro usuario, por lo general el superusuario (root), sin necesidad de cerrar la sesión actual en la misma terminal que estes usando y pudiendo acceder a todos los archivos, comandos y privilegios del usuario.

La sintaxis básica del comando "su" es la siguiente:

```
su [nombre del usuario]
```

`psql` inicia la herramienta de línea de comandos (**Cliente**) "**psql**" para interactuar con una base de datos PostgreSQL. Esto te permite ejecutar comandos SQL en la base de datos y realizar diferentes operaciones. Si tenes una base de datos configurada y en ejecución, podes usar "psql" para conectarte a ella e interactuar con ella.

```
psql
```

Para ejecutar PostgreSQL como servidor casi siempre en linux se lo ejecuta como servicio, para arrancarlo y empezar a usar después la instalación, se puede usar el siguiente comando:

```
sudo service postgresql start
```

El comando anterior va a ejecutar el servidor PostgreSQL en segundo plano.
Se puede verificar si se está ejecutando el servidor PostgreSQL con:

```
sudo service postgresql status
```

También se puede verificar el estado del servidor PostgreSQL con:

```
pg_ctl status
```